# Make path Relative fails because of copybuffer

Tags: packed-data, packing

I try to setup my scene for Renderfarm so i need to pack/unpuck all Resources and make them relative.
When i try to make Path Relative it has lots of fails.
I used ctrl+c(from old blend file) / ctrl+V(to new one)
how to clean up this errors abd those .blend path from my new scene?
[image: I think it creates coppybuffer]

Comment: If I understand it's a file that isn't accessible anymore? Do you have any form of reference to that file in your scene? Maybe try to set your Outliner to Blend-file display mode and search it from there.

Comment: thats the whole point.
can't find those nether in outliner -blend file , nor in orphan data

Comment: the scene looks correct. I just want to remove them.

Comment: non of file->clean up- s work

Comment: Are these errors blocking you from making other paths relative ?

Comment: no
as you could see 322 failed out of 452

Comment: Yes, but if all these errors are just these copybuffer files which you don't care about, then it's not really a problem, isn't it?

Comment: Thing is that concierge wont run render if files all the files are not relative,and if any kinde of report shows up during -report missing files. If there is any kind of error in scene -it wont run render even if i dont care about those coppybuffers.

Comment: could you try to upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so we can check ourselves ?

Comment: Sorry but its private. You can replicate this error bu creating new file adding cube and material with some texture -pack it, save file and copy the cube. Create another new file , paste cube - save it too in different destination and try to make path relative after packing textures

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. Make sure you are using Blender 3.4.1. And if it persists, maybe report it as a bug via the menu Help > Report A Bug.